# Shortcut to unindent a block on Mac/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos

How do I unindent a block on Eclipse/Mac? On my pc it used to be alt+tab, but on mac it's switching screens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either by menu (`Source > Shift left / right` or `Correct Indentation`) or by changing the keybindings in the preferences. But it is `Shift-Tab` for me, `Alt-Tab` switches application windows.